# Prove that for every p - prime, $p>3$ the numerator of sum of $p-1$ summands of harmonic series is divisible by $p$ square.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Prove that for every p - prime, $p>3$ the numerator of sum of $p-1$ summands of harmonic series is divisible by $p$ square.

I've written 1 A4 but so far without victory. This can't require advanced tools, as it is an exercise after chapter with only Euler's Theorem, Wilson's Theorem and CRT.

I've tried with Wilson's by multiplying everything by $(p-1)!$ and then write $(p-1)!=(p-1)*(p-2)!$ and later calculus -  but it does not work so far.

Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: This is known as [Wolstemholme's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wolstenholme%27s_theorem).

Comment: Note: in that duplicate the problem statement omits the (necessary requirement $p>3$) but the answer does state (and use) this assumption.

Comment: Yes, it answers my question. Thank You very much Mr @lulu